# Laravel 8 + MSSQL - ODBC driver queries invalid column using my Eloquent class name

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

So I have 2 models - `Order` and `File`, but I named classes like `EloquentOrder` and `EloquentFile` because I had to.

**Order** can have many files:

```
public function files(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(EloquentFile::class);
}
```

**File** belongs to order:

```
public function order(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(EloquentOrder::class);
}
```

**Columns for Orders:**

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('uuid');
    $table->string('index')->unique();
    $table->string('state');
    $table->string('short_name')->unique();
    $table->string('project_mass')->nullable();
    $table->string('customer')->nullable();
    $table->string('type')->nullable();
    $table->date('start_date')->nullable();
    $table->date('finish_date')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();

    // Indexes
    $table->primary('uuid');
});
```

**Columns for Files:**

```
Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('uuid');
    $table->text('name');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('size');
    $table->text('mime_type');
    $table->string('checksum')->unique();
    $table->uuid('order_uuid');
    $table->timestamps();

    // Indexes
    $table->primary('uuid');
});
```

I've created new Order…

[image]

…and I used it's primary key to create new file.

[image]

As soon as I try to fetch order with files I get ODBC exception:

```
$order = $this->orderRepository
    ->where('uuid', '=', 'a3b92a50-04e6-48b8-a7cc-e8128790d738')
    ->with([
        'files',
    ])
    ->all();
```

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC
> Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name
> 'eloquent_order_uuid'. (SQL: select * from [files] where
> [files].[eloquent_order_uuid] in
> (A3B92A50-04E6-48B8-A7CC-E8128790D738)) in file
> /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php
> on line 685

I see why this is happening: There is no column `eloquent_order_uuid`, there is `order_uuid`. Why MSSQL makes a concatenation with `eloquent_`. Without it it should be working. Am I doing something wrong?

This should be trivial - I've done this multiple time with MySQL but never with MSSQL driver.

Comment: You've got another issue also: the UUID doesn't have quotes.

Comment: Problem solved. See below. This was not a quote-related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to update relationship by passing `foreign key` and `local key`

In `EloquentOrder`  Model

```
public function files(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(EloquentFile::class,'order_uuid','uuid');
}
```

In `EloquentFile` model

```
public function order(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(EloquentOrder::class,'order_uuid','uuid');
}
```

Also  add `$primaryKey` property in model

```
protected  $primaryKey="uuid";
```

Also mention table name

```
 protected $table="orders"  in EloquentOrder model

 protected $table="files"  in EloquentFile model
```

Comment: OK, I forgot about second and third argument after `hasMany` and `belongsTo`. I already had table property specified. Thanks!

Comment: @MattKomarnicki. oh okay.np :)